# Unable To Install Tidyverse Due To Libcurl Issue

Tags: r, libcurl, tidyverse

I recently upgraded to R 3.5 and have been unable to install the 'tidyverse' package. Other packages are installing fine. Whenever I try to install tidyverse, I receive the following error message.

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/R/library/curl’
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/R/library/httr’
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rvest’
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/R/library/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHJ48Sk/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` as has been suggested on other threads for the same problem. However, this does not appear to resolve the issue (in fact, libcurl was already installed, and reinstalling it also did not work).

When I check $PATH, I do not see 'pkg-config', and PKG_CONFIG_PATH does not seem to exist. Adding `/usr/bin/pkg-config` to the path and setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH `/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc` also does not appear to have fixed the issue. I'm at wits end at this point, as I can't think of anything else to uninstall/reinstall, nor figure out why libcurl isn't being added to the path on its own when I install it. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: I have not faced this issue but I have faced similar ones with other dependencies. Based on the error message you may want to try setting your path to the directory that contains libcurl and not to libcurl itself, i.e. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig`

Comment: After two days of trying increasingly stupid things, that fixed it immediately. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Since that worked I went ahead and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting your path to the directory that contains libcurl and not to libcurl itself, i.e.

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this answer please. I am having a similar issue

Comment: @ChristopherKavazos the environment variable should point to a directory, not the file itself. OP originally set the env var to the *file* `/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc`. However, the env var should be set to the *directory* that contains the file `libcurl.pc`, it should not be set to the actual file itself. In this example the directory is `/home/nik/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig`, so that should be the value stored in the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.